# add servicestack.core to .net core library

Tags: servicestack

In servicestack angular 2 seed project services is in different solution which is helpful. But for some reason cannot install servicestack.core fails to add to .net core class library. Is it even possible to do the same thing with .net core project and expose "public class MyService : Service" in the different project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such limitation exists in ServiceStack .NET Core, you can check out different [ServiceStack .NET Core Live Demos](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/LiveDemos) for working examples.

Note: ServiceStack's .NET Core packages utilize a different `1.0.*` version number to ServiceStack's main .NET 4.5 Framework packages so you'll need to ensure you're adding a reference to the right version, you can check the [ServiceStack.Core NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Core) to find the latest version number, although it's recommended to just use a wild card, e.g:

```
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Core" Version="1.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Interfaces.Core" Version="1.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Text.Core" Version="1.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Client.Core" Version="1.0.*" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Common.Core" Version="1.0.*" />
```

Comment: @Roman ServiceStacks Server .NET Core packages targets .NET Standard 1.6, this is also listed in NuGet.